# Temporarily change my hosts title bar while using a TUI utility?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I have this TUI utility called, [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).
But I really dont like its hotkeys to make selections (tab to make multiple selections...)

I can solve this easily with AutoHotkey, issue is I need a way for AutoHotkey to know when FZ For Powershell is active in my terminal.

I am using the latest preview version of Windows Terminal.
Is there a way to change my hosts title bar and then revert back when FZF exits?

Just to be clear, I am looking for something like:

Windows Terminal Title - Pre FZF call (current directory is `C:\TEMP`):

```
PowerShell 7 - C:\TEMP
```

Windows Terminal Title - During FZF

```
PowerShell 7 - [[FZF MODE]]
```

Windows Terminal Title - After FZF exits

```
PowerShell 7 - C:\TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PowerShell, you could try something like:

```
$_old = [Console]::Title ; [Console]::Title = "foo" ; ping 8.8.8.8 ; [Console]::Title = $_old
```

Of course, replace the title as necessary, and the `ping` command with whatever you want (`fzf` in this case).

That will stash the old console title, set it to "foo", run ping, then restore the title after `ping` exits.

You *should* be able to alias `fzf` to that, so that it automatically does all that any time you type `fzf`, however, that's about where my pwsh knowledge runs out.